# How do I setup a cron job on OSX to launch a website in safari every 4 hours?

Tags: safari, cron

How do I setup a cron job on OSX to launch a website in safari every 4 hours? I'm looking to have it open on top of every window. It's basically a reminder for staff.

Comment: A reminder that this is a nuisance - loot at using notification or send emails - is interrupting them and so breaking their concentration what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
0 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * * open "http://google.com/"
```

<sup>The `0,4,8,12,16,20` is every hour that the cron will run (in this example, every 4th hour).</sup>

Comment: Do you know how I can open it and make the window go full screen? And it should open a new window not just a tab in my current window. Thank you.